# django-extra-views expose InlineFormSet field values into get_context_data() and forms_valid() methods

Tags: django, inline-formset

I would like to get access to fields of the InlineFormSet for consumption into the View.

Here is an example based on https://django-extra-views.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#createwithinlinesview-and-updatewithinlinesview:

```
from extra_views import InlineFormSet, CreateWithInlinesView,


class ItemsInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = Item


class TagsInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = Tag


class OrderCreateView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Order
    inlines = [ItemsInline, TagsInline]

    def get_success_url(self):
        return self.object.get_absolute_url()
```

How do I expose the InlineFormSet fields in the *get_context_data()* and *forms_valid()* methods? 
**Warning:** Code below fails!

```
class OrderCreateView(CreateWithInlinesView):

    [... see above ...]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrderCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['items'] = ItemsInline(self.request.POST)
            context['tags'] = TagsInline(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['items'] = ItemsInline()
            context['tags'] = TagsInline()
        return context

    def forms_valid((self, form, inlines):

        [...]    

        return super(OrderCreateView, self).forms_valid(form, inlines)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reproduced your example with this models:

```
STATUS_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'Placed'),
    (1, 'Charged'),
    (2, 'Shipped'),
    (3, 'Cancelled'),
)

class Order(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    action_on_save = models.BooleanField(default=False)


class Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=13)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, db_index=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    status = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, db_index=True)
    date_placed = models.DateField(default=now, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s (%s)' % (self.item_name, self.sku)


class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.tag_name
```

Urls:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from .views import OrderCreateView, OrderUpdateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^inlines/new/$', OrderCreateView.as_view()),
    url(r'^inlines/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', OrderUpdateView.as_view()),
]
```

Forms:

```
from django import forms
from .models import Order, Item


class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['name']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        instance = super(OrderForm, self).save(commit=commit)
        if commit:
            instance.action_on_save = True
            instance.save()
        return instance


class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    flag = forms.BooleanField(initial=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['item_name', 'sku', 'price', 'order', 'status']
```

Views:

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from extra_views import InlineFormSet, CreateWithInlinesView, UpdateWithInlinesView
from extra_views.generic import GenericInlineFormSet
from .forms import OrderForm
from .models import Item, Order, Tag


class ItemsInline(InlineFormSet):
    model = Item
    fields = ['item_name', 'sku', 'price', 'order', 'status']


class TagsInline(GenericInlineFormSet):
    model = Tag
    fields = ['tag_name']


class OrderCreateView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    model = Order
    fields = ['name']
    context_object_name = 'order'
    inlines = [ItemsInline, TagsInline]
    template_name = 'extra_views/order_and_items.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return '/inlines/%i' % self.object.pk


class OrderUpdateView(UpdateWithInlinesView):
    model = Order
    form_class = OrderForm
    inlines = [ItemsInline, TagsInline]
    template_name = 'extra_views/order_and_items.html'

    def get_success_url(self):
        return ''
```

- In `OrderCreateView` you cannot read `Tag` and `Item` records in the
  `get_context_data` method because they haven't been created.
- In `OrderCreateView` you can read all records after the `forms_valid`
  method as usual.
- In `OrderUpdateView` you can read all records in the
  `get_context_data` method like in the `forms_valid` method.

It looks like this:

```
class OrderCreateView(CreateWithInlinesView):
    # ... 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super(OrderCreateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        from pprint import pprint
        pprint(self.request.POST)  # there is only post data here
        return data

    def forms_valid(self, form, inlines):
        instance = super(OrderCreateView, self).forms_valid(form, inlines)
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model)
        print('all items', [item.item_name for item in self.object.items.all()])  # items
        print('all tags', [tag.tag_name for tag in
                           TagsInline.model.objects.filter(content_type=ct, object_id=self.object.id)])  # tags
        return instance

class OrderUpdateView(UpdateWithInlinesView):
    # ... 

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(OrderUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model)
        print('all items', [item.item_name for item in self.object.items.all()])  # items
        print('all tags', [tag.tag_name for tag in
                           TagsInline.model.objects.filter(content_type=ct, object_id=self.object.id)])  # tags
        return context
```

Comment: Sorry, this does not seem to work. I try to add inlines_names = ['items', 'tags'] to directly access named variables, because I don't know how to access 'inline_instance'. Can you please be more explicit? Thank you!

Comment: Oh, you would like read the data from models, not `InlineFormSet` fields. I updated the answer, please check.